# Building a project changes another project's bin folder in a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

I've dozens of web applications and lots of class libraries in a solution. When I build a web application, let's say "A", another web application project, let's say "B", affected by this compiling. The "A" and "B" are not referenced directly, but they uses same class libraries. If I build or rebuild "A", the created assemblies by this build goes to the "B"'s bin folder, too. So, everytime I build "A", I'm waiting the startup of the "B". As far as I know, there isn't any hardlink/symlink between these bin folders of the projects.

Also, I'm using common output path for class libraries, but not for web applications.

Is this a bug or default behavior? How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug or default behavior? How can I prevent this behavior?

This is default behavior. Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project, the following are added to your Web project's Bin folder:

- **A copy of the assembly created from the added project.**
- Copies of dependent assemblies, XML document files, license files, resource files, and so on.

So once you add the library project to web, the assembly from the added project will automatically add to the web project`s Bin folder.

If you want to prevent this behavior, you can pack the class libraries as a NuGet package, then add that package to the web project A and B. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package) for more info about NuGet create package.